# How to return to same place on a page that has a 'read more' button without having to re-click the 'read more'.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section which fades out and a 'read more' link/button. The rest of the section, that opens up, is quite long and has links to external sites. Is there any way to link away and come back to my page with the section still displayed, because at the moment when I return the page refreshes and the user has to scroll, open the 'read more' again scroll again to find the previous place on the page which is not good. It would be great if the user could return to the same place in the page, with the section fully displayed, at least until they have finished the article or session. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #fade-wrap {
             position: relative;
             height: 10rem;
             margin-bottom: 3rem;
             overflow: hidden;
           }
          #fade-out {
             position: absolute;
             bottom: 0;
             height: 5rem;
             width: 100%;
           }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <section>
          <div>
            <p>
              Some text ...
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="fade-wrap">
            <p>
              Some text ...
            </p>
            <p>
              Some more text ...
            </p>
          <div id="fade-out"></div>
          </div>
            <p>
              <a id="read-more" 
                 href="javascript:seeMore()">Read More &#8811;</a>
            </p>
         </section>
       <footer>
       </footer>
         <script>
           function seeMore()
            {
              document.getElementById("fade-wrap").style.height = "auto";
              document.getElementById("fade-out").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("read-more").style.display = "none";
            }
         </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not much, just Googled for about an hour and tried some stuff with :visited but obviously that didn't work ...my knowledge is quite limited. It took me ages just to sort the JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to play with #anchor on url, to deal with current page state.

```
<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                #fade-wrap {
                     position: relative;
                     height: 10rem;
                     margin-bottom: 3rem;
                     overflow: hidden;
                 }
                #fade-out {
                     position: absolute;
                     bottom: 0;
                     height: 5rem;
                     width: 100%;
                 }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Some text ...
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="fade-wrap">
                    <p>
                        Some text ...
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Some more text ...
                    </p>
                <div id="fade-out"></div>
                </div>
                    <p>
                        <a id="read-more" 
                             href="javascript:seeMore()">Read More &#8811;</a>
                    </p>
             </section>
         <footer>
         </footer>
             <script>
                 function seeMore()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("fade-wrap").style.height = "auto";
                        document.getElementById("fade-out").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("read-more").style.display = "none";
                        //Add anchor to keep track readMore is open.
                        window.location.href = "#open";
                    }
                    // if we detect anchor on url
                    if (window.location.href.match(/\#open/i)) 
                    {
                        //Scroll to read-more id
                        document.querySelector('#read-more'). scrollIntoView();
                        //Display items
                        seeMore();
                    }
             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked a treat in Chrome and Opera ...they return to the same place in th expanded page. Firefox, IE, and Edge keep the page expanded but bring you back to where the anchor is so not so good. I will take the advice from @Gray and look into localStorage API's although I'm not familiar with it and am busy trying to learn JavaScript. Thanks for your help though much appreciated.

Comment: Approch of Gray is much better to keep saved some user information. But is linked to your browser, and will not work if you just want to share URL who will go to expended content. If you want to scroll to specific item onLoad, just change "document.querySelector('#read-more'). scrollIntoView();" by your section selector. And will work ;) if no, please provide us sample

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean, could you give more info?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#read-more').scrollIntoView()` scroll view to #read-more tag. if you want to scroll to 'fade-out' you have to replace bellow code by : document.querySelector('#read-more').scrollIntoView().

----

Now about anchor on url, such as : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts who don't go on same scroll than https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/. When user will share with #open anchor on url, new visitor will automatically go to the right place.

Comment: Ah okay I see now, thanks, that is a good idea which I hadn't thought of ...I thought you were referring to the Firefox issue. If you have any ideas on why that is happening with FF, IE, and Edge I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest researching the localStorage API that is found in most modern browsers. You could use JavaScript to save the user's last known 'state' of the page, which would then give you information to work with on their next visit.

For example, you could set a state like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('myUsersPreviousState', 'section_expanded');
```

Then a future call to:

```
var previous_state = localStorage.getItem('myUsersPreviousState');
```

...will return 'section_expanded'.

With that, you could say:

```
if ( previous_state === 'section_expanded' ) {
    // javascript to expand section and scroll to location
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gray I will try with this but my knowledge of JavaScript is very limited so it might be beyond my capability right now.